# False-branch of if constexpr not discarded in templated lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, if-constexpr

I have a problem with "if constexpr" in a templated lambda. For the sake of argument let's ignore how I got there, but I have a struct foo that is defined in some way to result in something as follows:

```
template<bool condition>
struct foo {
    int a;

    // Only contains b if condition is true
    int b;
}
```

Now I can define a templated function thtemplate

```
template<bool condition>
void print_fun(foo & obj) {
    /* Do something with obj.a */
    if constexpr(condition)
        /* Do something with obj.b */
};
```

Instantiating this function and using it will compile, if the constexpr parameter to `foo` is the same as the one to `print_fun`, i.e.

```
constexpr bool no = false;
foo<no> obj = {};
print_fun<no>(obj);
```

This does compile because the false branch is discarded inside a templated entity, and thus there is no problem with using obj.b inside print_fun.

However, if I define a similar lambda expression as follows:

```
template<bool condition>
auto print_lambda = [](foo & obj) {
    /* Do something with obj.a */
    if constexpr(condition)
        /* Do something with obj.b */
};
```

and instantiate it:

```
constexpr bool no = false;
foo<no> obj = {};
print_lambda<no>(obj);
```

then the false branch is not discarded and the compiler gives me

> 'b': is not a member of 'foo'

Is this intended behavior, does it happen on other compilers?
Am I doing something wrong?
Or is it a bug in the compiler? (Microsoft Visual Studio Version 15.4.1, gcc 7.2)

Check out my test [here](https://godbolt.org/g/CPsgAQ) with gcc, where it does not compile for a functor or function either.

Edit:
Here is the code of a my minimal example, I was not aware that the external link wouldn't suffice. This compiles on Visual Studio 15.4.1, except for the noted line.
`foo_bar` takes the place of `foo` in my description.

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr bool no = false;

struct foo {
    int x;
};

struct bar {
    int y;
};

template <bool, typename AlwaysTy, typename ConditionalTy>
struct Combined : AlwaysTy {};

template <typename AlwaysTy, typename ConditionalTy>
struct Combined<true, AlwaysTy, ConditionalTy> : AlwaysTy, ConditionalTy {};

using foo_bar = Combined<no, foo, bar>;

template<bool condition>
void print_fun(foo_bar & obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
    if constexpr(condition)
        std::cout << obj.y << std::endl;
};

template<bool condition>
auto print_lambda = [](foo_bar & obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
    if constexpr(condition)
        std::cout << obj.y << std::endl;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    foo_bar obj = {};
    print_lambda<no>(obj); // Does not compile
    print_fun<no>(obj);
}
```

Comment: "constexpr used to create foo". constexprs do not create anything. Multiple parts of your question are confusing, and cannot be parsed. You need to include a specific [mcve] that demonstrates the compilation error you're asking about, so that everyone can see it for themselves, instead of having to guess what it is. And you must include it ***in the question itself***, instead of a link to some external web site that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. Most people on stackoverflow.com ignore external links in the question, for that reason.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the example. Sorry for the confusion, I just didn't want to go into detail of how foo came to be different based on a constexpr, but I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the code linked,

```
template<bool condition>
void print_fun(foo_bar & obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
    if constexpr(condition)
        std::cout << obj.y << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is with [if constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) being used, the statement `std::cout << obj.y << std::endl;` is ill-formed for every possible instantiation of the template `print_fun`; i.e. no matter what's the value of `condition` it's just always ill-formed.

> Note: the discarded statement can't be ill-formed for every possible specialization:
>
> The common workaround for such a catch-all statement is a type-dependent expression that is always false:

To fix it you can make the statement to dependent on the template parameter, e.g.

```
template <bool condition>
using foo_bar = Combined<condition, foo, bar>;

template<bool condition>
void print_fun(foo_bar<condition> & obj) {
    std::cout << obj.x << std::endl;
    if constexpr(condition)
        std::cout << obj.y << std::endl;
}
```

and use it as

```
foo_bar<no> obj = {};
print_fun<no>(obj);
```

Now for `obj.y`, `obj` is of type `foo_bar<condition>`, which depends on the template parameter `condition`.

[LIVE](https://godbolt.org/g/W4s7zA)

Comment: Interestingly I see this now compiling on the live example, but it makes no difference when compiling the code in Visual Studio. The function and the functor work as before, while the lambda still emits the same warning.

Comment: @HannoBänsch I doesn't have VS, so what's the message? (Is it just a warning?) BTW I tested and the code compiles with both GCC and Clang.

Comment: The same error as mentioned in the question. I understand the reason why previously it should not have worked, but now it seems more likely that VS has a bug, if constexpr was not even supported some months ago.

Comment: @HannoBänsch I'm not sure but I also guess it's a VS's bug. `if constepr` or lambda might not be supported completely.

Comment: Do you agree with me accepting this answer? I strongly believe I will have to contact Microsoft to solve the problem, while your solution clearly agrees with the standard and works in other compilers.

Comment: @HannoBänsch I agree. :) And you might post another question focusing on the different behavior between VS and other compilers.