# Constexpr if with non-template types

Tags: c++, c++17, if-constexpr

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int x) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(x), std::string>) {
        x = std::string();
    }
}

int main(void)
{ return 0; }
```

This code doesn't compile on either GCC 7 nor Clang 5:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘int’ in assignment
         x = std::string();
```

Since the referenced line is in a constexpr if branch that should evaluate to `false`, shouldn't the program compile fine?

Comment: This is the expected behavior, surprisingly enough. `if constexpr` doesn't work in this way, only (roughly) for template parameters

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46512248/2069064) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47000914/2069064)

Comment: I do agree with you though. I don't understand why the code you wrote wasn't specified to work. I find it surprising. There are certainly cases where it would be desirable, such as build settings, or target-specific settings

Comment: @Justin You think it's surprising that assigning a `string` to an `int` doesn't work? I would be curious to see such use-cases...

Comment: @Barry I guess if I actually think it through, yeah that would be a bug in every case. But there was a couple cases of `if constexpr` that didn't do what I expected, unless I was mistaken. The more I think about it, the more I think I just didn't think it through in those cases....

Comment: @Barry preprocessor-generated code, where the action is conditional on the macro types. I know, templates are usually better than macros, but in some circumstances it's just simpler and cleaner to use classic macros.

Comment: @Justin just where I am right now, with build settings and I found this problem. I am a bit disappointed that if constexpr is limited to template functions only :(

Answer (score 4):

The `if constexpr` specification defines the *discarded statement*. It then goes on to define that the discarded statement is not instantiated when the result is not value-dependent *after* instantiation. The implication is that statements are discarded during template instantiation. Further, the statement is only discarded if the conditional value is dependent on the template arguments.